# Has a $L^1$ bounded sequence a weak converging subsequence in $L^2$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $f_n \in L^2(0,1)$ with the property that
$\sup_n || f_n ||_{L^1}<A< \infty$, i.e. $f_n$ is a sequence in $L^2$ that is uniformly bounded in the $L^1$-Norm.

Does $f_n$ then have a weak converging subsequence in $L^2$?

i.e. is there a $f \in L^2$ and $n_k$, such that $ \int gf_{n_k} \rightarrow  \int gf$ for all $g \in L^2(0,1)$?

Comment: No. Take $f_n=n\chi_{(0,1/n]}$.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by David Mitra, the answer is no.

In fact, a sequence which converges weakly in $L^2$ is bounded in $L^2$. Conversely, a sequence bounded in $L^2$ possesses a subsequence which converges weakly in $L^2$.

Hence, at least a subsequence of your $\{f_n\}$ has to be bounded in $L^2$, which might not be true for all sequences which are bounded in $L^1$.